# JQuery Validate Plugin allowing the post of invalid data

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following validation rules to my form:

```
function ValidadeRegistration() {
$('#RegistrationForm').validate({
    rules: {
         "auth.UserName": {
            required : true,
            email: true
        },
        "auth.Password": {
            required : true,
            minlenght : 5
        },
        PasswordConfirmation: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "auth.UserName": {
            email: 'Por favor digite um e-mail v&aacute;lido.',
            required: 'Campo e-mail obrigat&oacute;rio.'
        },
        "auth.Password": {
            required: 'Campo senha obrigat&oacute;rio.',
            minlength: 'A sua senha deve conter ao menos 5 caract$eacute;res.'    
        },
        "PasswordConfirmation": {
            required: 'Confirmação da senha é obrigat&oacute;ria.',
            equalTo : 'A senha não bate.'
        }
    }
});
```

}

The error messages display  correctly and the plugin blocks the post when I have invalid data in any of the fields, however all it takes to allow the post is presence of data in the "auth.Password" field. If I have anything written in this field (it doesn't even have to be in the length specified) the plugin ignores all other errors and posts.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: minlength is misspelled for auth.Password. Does it work if this is corrected?

Comment: Thank you! Needless to say I feel very stupid now!
Ok, I admit it: I am an Intellisense addict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`minlength` is misspelled:

Current:

```
    "auth.Password": {
        required : true,
        minlenght : 5
    },
```

Corrected:

```
    "auth.Password": {
        required : true,
        minlength : 5
    },
```